# Indicate if a user is 'online' via their user info panel

Tags: feature-request

I am not sure if it's called a "user info" panel or not, but I am referring to the user information panel that is displayed at the foot of each question/answer.

It would be useful (certainly for myself, but hopefully others too) if we could see at a glance if the user is online.

The definition of "online" might be something such as if the user has been active in the last 10 minutes (which is based on the "seen" date/time).

The design could be something as simple as just including a small green circle for users that are currently "online" and a different colour (red, grey etc.) for users not online, for example:

[image]

[image]

The icon could then have a hover tool tip which displays last seen time. For example: `"seen 8 mins ago"`.

The reason why I think this would be beneficial is because the most common reason I view a user profile is to see if they are active or not (surely I am not the only one who does this?). This would save me the time of having to navigate to another page just to work out when the user was last seen, and that means less page requests which is always nice.

Comment: With the mobile app, users get notifications all the time. And you can configure to receive notifications by email. I really don't want to be pestered by people thinking I am online. We have the chat rooms for that kind of direct communication.

Comment: Besides, people should focus on the **content**. That we use humans to produce the content is pesky detail.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: But it is based on last seen time which is already available anyway. Why would this be any different?

Comment: @musefan: It puts the information right in the post when it should really stay in the profile.

Comment: Because **the content page you should focus on the content**. And it doesn't really matter if someone has been seen in the past 10 minutes, because they can still ignore notifications, *or* get those notifications by other means that won't update the 'seen' counter.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Sorry, but if that's your argument then why show any user info at all? Why do we care how many badges people have? The point I am making is I often click a user profile just to see if they are active (whatever my reasons, I do this often) it would be nice not to have to load the whole profile just to find out the seen time.

Comment: I do the same, but perhaps not enough people do that to make this a worthwhile consideration. Perhaps you may be decent enough not to pester people just because they are online, but I can imagine a lot more users who are less considerate.

Comment: The reason rep and badges are displayed is because they indicate how much you can trust what a user has written at first blush. This information is not time-sensitive. A user's online status is - and while we typically recommend that users stick around to address immediate concerns about the stuff they post, it shouldn't be an obligation.

Comment: @BoltClock: The end goal for me is to basically see the last seen time quicker. If the worry is about people being pestered then let's come up with a solution that still provides the info but doesn't suggest `"hey im online, please talk to me"`

Comment: @BoltClock: And badges mean nothing, I have seen people with 100 gold badges just because they asked lots of questions a few years back (view badges). They don't provide any meaningful indicator. Whereas rep I agree with you, is useful

Comment: @musefan: Might be a good case for hiding badges - along with Jon Skeet's ever-growing numbers which seem only to make the designers increase the width of this element every time they bump up a digit.

Answer (score 8):

No, please don't add a status indicator to the user card. Stack Overflow is not a social network.

- The content page should focus on the content alone. That the content was produced by humans is a pesky detail.
- The 'last seen' indicator does in no way tell you if someone is paying attention or not. With the mobile apps and notifications sent to you by email, as well as [API-based notification apps](https://stackapps.com/search?q=%5Bapp%5D+notification) people receive your comments in many different ways. And users recently seen could still be ignoring your messages, perhaps because they are [auto-reloading the reviews page](https://stackapps.com/questions/4086/review-stalker-user-script).
- I don't want to be pestered to provide answers in comments because people think I am online. I'll be in a chat room if I am available to be talked to.

There are probably technical reasons not to do this either; the Stack Exchange servers serve [185 requests per second](https://stackexchange.com/performance), the majority of which are question pages. If all those pages then also start asking the server for a status indicator for every user on the page, you have a scalability nightmare.

Comment: This request isn't about finding somebody to talk to. Lets says for example I come across a question from a few hours ago, it's unclear so I leave a comment for clarification. Now, this is when I want to now how active the user is. If the user is active then I will frequently check to see if they have responded so I can provide more info/answer. If the user hasn't been seen for a couple of hours then I wont keep an eye on it, as it's unlikely they will respond anytime soon. Ultimately, I have other stuff to do and the seen time is a good indicator of how often I will check for notifications

Comment: @musefan: no, but it'll be *used* to find people to talk to. Just because you are that decent doesn't mean others are. I get LinkedIn requests and people using my online contact form and twitter all the time to ask me to answer their questions already.

Comment: @musefan: For posts, just leave comments and move on. Responsible question askers will stick around and respond.

Comment: So we design it so it doesn't give the impression users are online to talk. My green/red icon was just one option for displayed the information. It doesn't have to be so obvious that it encourages pestering. Imagine a question from a day ago, I want to help thus I want to know how frequently I should check back with SO. Askers can't sit on SO until they get a response, some question just can't be answered within 5 minutes of asking.

Comment: @musefan: you too get notified of actions o your posts. Votes, comments, etc. Why should you check back based on their activity? Design is not going to help here, recently active still means recently active.

Comment: But it does help me. And I don't get notifications anywhere other than the red box at the top of the website page